# Is this the denial of a statement, or a statement of denial?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particle-と

This sentence originally came from a newspaper article. Unfortunately, I copied it onto a flashcard for later study and then lost the original context.

> 彼は、可能性について「念頭に全くない」と否定した。
>
> 【かれは、かのうせいに　ついて　「ねんとうに　まったくない」と　ひていした。

What I'm confused about is the end part that says `と否定した`. Does it mean that he denied the statement, or that he was denying the possibility?

Which of these following translations is more correct?

- Speaking of the possibilities, he denied saying "it's totally not on my mind."
- Speaking of the possibilities, he denied them, saying "it's totally not on my mind."

Comment: I believe it's a statement of denial. If he were denying the statement it would probably be something like 〜ことを否定した — i.e. with a direct object instead of a quote.

Comment: The latter makes far more sense in English, and in common-sense terms, really. It would take quite a strange circumstance to deny saying that you weren't considering a possibility...

Comment: @Dave it's more that it's a strange thing to end up having to deny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Possibly this was the original context, and you cut it down for the flashcard?
http://ch25oda.kitaguni.tv/e1678763.html )

He is denying "可能性", and 「念頭に全くない」 is quoting the phrasing he used to deny it.

You can think of it as close to:

> 彼は、可能性について「念頭に全くない」と言って否定した。
>
> "Regarding the possibility, he denied it, saying..."

As opposed to:

> 彼は、可能性について「念頭に全くない」と言ったことを否定した。
>
> "Regarding the possiblity, he denied saying that..."

Indirect quoting is also fine:

> 念頭に全くないと否定した。

Alternative arrangement with similar meaning:

> 「念頭に全くない」と可能性を否定した。

Another example utilising a quote + associated verb, and then を否定、 since I just saw it pop up on Yomiuri:

> 「中国政府は一貫してハッカー攻撃に反対している。中国も国外からのハッカー攻撃を受けている主要な被害国であり、中国がハッカー攻撃を仕掛ける拠点との見解は根拠がない」などと述べ、中国の関与を否定した。